# 3D collision detection with MatGeoLib?

Tags: c++, 3d, collision-detection

I am writing a plug-in in C++ for some dedicated server software which hosts servers for a game.

I looked around for 3D Collision libraries but it's really hard to find any with examples, but I decided to use MathGeoLib because it looks promising - but it lacks examples and I am unable to find any.

So my question is: How would I define a sphere and a cube, a line (Point+direction)  and then get the Position XYZ of the first collision which the line encounters?

The documentation only shows the classes and which methods they have. But nothing show how to start using MathGeoLib. Are there any tutorials which are not findable on google?

---

Background information on my project:

I am making a collision detector for San Andreas Multiplayer, the server has no information whatsover on the game world so I decided to extract the collision files and object placement files and convert them to a usable format for my plug-in.

The objects have a position XYZ and quaternion rotation XYZW and the collision files, well, [have lots of stuff in them](http://www.gtamodding.com/index.php?title=Collision_File) [a project member is writing a parser for those .col files for the project].

The project goals are to provide a mechanism to determine the Z position based on the XY position and to provide a ray-tracer which tells you where a line (StartPos,EndPos) intersects (hit XYZ) in the game world.

This is why I need to know how to accomplish this with MathGeoLib. I'm going to load all the object collisions into one world and then execute the ray tracer functions. (Amount of objects is around 30,000 in a 6000x6000x1000 area)

Comment: Gizmo, have you tried bullet, by the way?

Comment: no, couldn't find it under "C++ 3D collision library", it's a game physics engine.. ?

Comment: are the collision detection things exposed/usable by me?

Comment: we used in a game development and distribution framework, called "Gluon" for collision detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out

http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/

Bullet is an open source physics engine and comes with lots of example code. In particular you want to use the rayTest() method of a dynamics world to cast a ray and return the nearest collision point. To summarize you'll need to; create a dynamics world, load your sphere and cube data into it, and then call `rayTest(startPoint, endPoint, resultCallback);`

Assuming you haven't used bullet before start with the "hello world" example code to see how you can easily create a dynamics world and add rigid bodies to it.

Comment: I wonder if it is ok for the author to switch to Bullet as I also suggested, or he really looks for a solution with matgeolib. I have never used that library myself though. :)

Comment: I don't mind as long as I can get the collision point :) that's what my plugin is about, I started today so switching is not hard. I will check bullet, hello world example is understandable.. but the tutorials page is [empty](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Bullet_Tutorials)...

Comment: nvm I see the page [moved to here](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Tutorial_Articles). going to try it out

Comment: If you go with Bullet you should also check out the Multithreaded dispatcher example "SpuGatheringCollisionDispatcher" after you wrap your head around the hello world example. I added it to my game project and it cut the sim time in half. :-)